# Default routing in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When I was working with Web API 2, I found that there is slight change in routing of web api.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I understand the working of routing. Also I found that, by default there is no method name in routing although we can modify the routing and can add add pattern for action/method. But my question is what was the idea behind creating such routing.

Thank you
Susheel

Comment: could you please clarify your question? do you mean by "idea behind creating such routing" the routing mechanism in general? and to what change in routing are you referring? a different version? if yes, which previous one and what is the current version you are testing with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no actions because the idea is that you can have a method for each ***HTTP verb***. e.g.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()

public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)

public IHttpActionResult Post()

public IHttpActionResult Put(int id)
```

The verb used determines which method is called.

The idea is that controllers are supposed to be very specific about what they relate to.
So you may have a "PersonController" which deals with adding and updating people, and an "OrdersController" which deals with orders.

Obviously this doesn't work out quite as straightforward in practice because controllers end up being more wide ranging than CRUD operations for an entity type.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me up from confusion.